# How to select rows that have min value from a column but has an if statement in SQL based on another Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PersonID int,
    Diagnosis varchar(255),
    ConsultantID varchar(255),
    EpisodeNumber varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, Diagnosis,ConsultantID, EpisodeNumber)
VALUES (1, 'Headache','001', 1),
       (1, 'Headache','001', 2),
       (1, 'Stomachache','002', 1),
       (1, 'Bone Fracture','002', 2),
       (2, 'Headache', '003',1),
       (2, 'Headache', '003',2),
       (3, 'Hand','004', 1),
       (3, 'Headache','003', 1);
```

I have created the table above as an example and the table would look like this:

[image]

I would like to select the rows based on the PersonID, The consultant ID and ( the Minimum EpisodeNumber unless there is different diagnosis for the PersonID). For Example, the desired output would be as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (
     select * , row_number() over (partition by PersonID,Diagnosis,ConsultantID order by EpisodeNumber) rn
     from Persons
) t where rn = 1
```

| PersonID | Diagnosis | ConsultantID | EpisodeNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bone Fracture | 002 | 2 |
| 1 | Headache | 001 | 1 |
| 1 | Stomachache | 002 | 1 |
| 2 | Headache | 003 | 1 |
| 3 | Hand | 004 | 1 |
| 3 | Headache | 003 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36a2e37d3b60711dc300564f291bd320)*

Comment: How do you know that it over sql-server?

Comment: @4EACH this code works in almost any modern RDBMS

Comment: @4EACH in the same fiddle I have provided in the answer , just change the database engine to "MySQL 8" and click on run . you can also choose Postgresql , MariaDB, etc

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
select personid, diagnosis, consultantid, min(episodenumber) as episodenumber
from Persons
group by personid, diagnosis, consultantid;
```

that will generate the result you posted. Either it is this simple or your example is not sufficient to explain what the problem is.